# Sign tool not recognised when using Inno Script Studio compiler from command prompt

Tags: inno-setup, code-signing

I am signing my installer with a digital certificate. When using Inno Script Studio, I have correctly defined my sign tool with a path to the MS signing tool, certificate password etc. And I simply reference it with

```
SignTool=signtool
```

And this works fine.

But when I try and compile my script via the command line using:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Inno Setup 5>iscc "C:\Users\username\Documents\MyInstaller.iss"
```

I get an error:

> Value of [Setup] section directive "SignTool" is invalid.

When I read [the documentation, it states](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=compilercmdline):

> any Sign Tools configured using the Compiler IDE will be specified automatically

So my understanding is that I shouldn't have to use the `/S` parameter? What is the correct way to sign a setup file when building from the command line?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Inno Script Studio uses a different set of "sign tools" than Inno Setup.

Inno Script Studio stores the "sign tools" to:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Kymoto Solutions\Inno Script Studio 2\SignTools
```

While Inno Setup stores them to:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Jordan Russell\Inno Setup\SignTools
```

So, the Inno Setup command-line compiler `iscc.exe` is not aware of your Inno Script Studio sign tools.

You can probably simply export the `SignTools` from `Inno Script Studio 2` and import them to the `Inno Setup` registry, as the syntax seems identical.