# Inno Setup SignTool is invalid when command run from DevOps

Tags: azure-devops, inno-setup, code-signing

I have configured Sign Tool (named `MySigningTool`) using Inno Setup Complier app (Tools -> Configure Sign Tools) and have used the below line in .ISS file.

```
[Setup]
SignTool = MySigningTool $f
```

I run below command and this works on my local machine.

```
"ISCC.exe" "/DSourcePath=%arg1%" InnoSetupScript_DevBuild.iss
```

But when the same command is triggered from Azure DevOps pipeline, I get an error saying:

> Value of `[Setup]` section directive `"SignTool"` is invalid.

I have tried solution provided at [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36640899/sign-tool-not-recognised-when-using-inno-script-studio-compiler-from-command-pro) but still not working.

Any idea why it runs locally but not from DevOps?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Well, as you defined the sign tool on your local machine, and as you know that the sign tool is stored in Windows Registry, you cannot be really surprised that you cannot refer to the sign tool definition on another machine.*

Instead, define the sign tool on your [`iscc` commandline](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=compilercmdline):

```
iscc /SMySigningTool=... ...
```

See also [Providing SignTool configuration in Inno Setup script](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53449048/850848)